# Can I bring metoprolol tartrate to Japan?

Tags: japan, health

At somepoint in the future I would like to take a trip to Japan. I am from the United States and I have a chronic illness that requires me to take metoprolol tartrate. I know that certain prescription drugs cannot be taken to Japan, however I can't find information about whether I can bring metoprolol tartrate or not. Would this be allowed?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, non-psychoactive drugs are *almost* always fine to take to any given country. That's not a hard-and-fast rule, of course, but it suggests that if you haven't found anyone saying you can't take it with you, "no news is good news".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metoprolol tartrate is not a psychoactive/narcotic ingredient (at least not according to the Japanese government), so it is not restricted or prohibited, and you need only follow the usual procedures to import prescription drugs into Japan. Normally, a permit will be required; however, if the quantity to be imported is **1 month worth or less** (as this is a prescription drug), you may import it without filing an application.

TL;DR: don't worry. Bring your prescription and simply declare it at the customs; they'll perform a check and let you through.

See: [Japan Customs FAQ Page](https://www.customs.go.jp/english/c-answer_e/imtsukan/1806_e.htm)

Comment: This response was helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

There is an [official page](https://www.ncd.mhlw.go.jp/en/application2.html) from the narcotics control department listing the controlled substances and the procedures for carrying prescription drugs when entering Japan.

> When you enter/leave Japan carrying your medicine containing controlled substances in Japan for your own medical use, you need to get a permission in advance.
>
> Procedure depends on the category of the controlled substances; the category is divided into Narcotics, Psychotropics, Stimulants, Stimulants' Raw Materials, Cannabis and Opium.
>
> Some medicines can't be imported/exported to/from Japan, even if these are prescription medicines in your country.
> First of all, you must check which category your medicine belongs to and go through the corresponding procedure.

Searching the list for metoprolol returned 0 results. However the page suggests

> The list does not include brand names of medicines.
>
> If you are not sure, you should check the category of your medicine with the doctor who prescribed your medicine.

Since I am not a doctor, I would suggest you to follow the advice and check the with your doctor.

Comment: This response was very helpful and answered my question, thank you.